# How to create a Choince column with Multiple values in SharePoint List?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, csom, sharepoint-list

I must be missing something but I am unable to find a way, either in Graph or Sharepoint CSOM to create a Choice column in a SharePoint List with this setting to ON.

[image]

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set the field type to `MultiChoice` instead of `Choice` and omit the `Format` attribute:

```cs
/// from: https://karinebosch.wordpress.com/my-articles/creating-fields-using-csom/
/// 
string schemaChoiceField = "<Field ID='##YOUR-GUID##' Type='MultiChoice' Name='SideDishesChoice' StaticName='SideDishesChoice' 
   DisplayName = 'Side dishes' >"
    "<Default>Patatoes</Default>"
            "<CHOICES>"
            "    <CHOICE>Fresh vegetables</CHOICE>"
            "    <CHOICE>Beans</CHOICE>"
            "    <CHOICE>Pepper Sauce</CHOICE>"
            "</CHOICES>"
    "</Field>";
Field choiceField = demoList.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(schemaChoiceField, true, AddFieldOptions.AddFieldInternalNameHint);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Basically any combination that you can do using UI should be doable with API, you can just export the list as XML, then look at the exported markup and just use the same for `AddFieldAsXml`

Comment: For Microsoft graph the type column is unfortunately read-only, so this method will not work. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/columndefinition?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties

Comment: @AnthonyPhan if you are using graph api to modify the column you will probably need to drop and recreate it.

Comment: Unfortunately creating a column with this set also does not work. I think there is a limitation with MS Graph.